# In FFMPEG what is the most efficient method for resizing a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a large collection of mkv and mp4 video files in 4:3 format. I am trying to resize the largest of them, down to a more manageable 640x480 size. This is partly to save disk space, but also to make them easier to watch on a laptop screen, and to consume fewer processor cycles to play them.

But I haven't found an efficient means of resizing them. I have been trying to adhere closely to the encoding used for the original file, as reported by MediaInfo (using the x264opts option to reproduce the variables reported by MediaInfo, where they differ from a standard preset). Based on 2-pass video encoding.

But this leaves me with a very complex command for ffmpeg, shown below. What am I overlooking? Is there a more straightforward command line I can use with ffmpeg, which will still do a fair job of reproducing the encoding used in the input file?

```
::  Resize Image to 640x480 (e.g. 960x720 x 2/3)

::  Input File (WITH .ext)
SET input=video_960x720_320kbps.mkv

::  Resize from 960x720 to 640x480 (i.e. 960x720 x 2/3)

::  Resize Picture to 2/3rd
    SET multiply=2
    SET divide=3

::  Location of FFMPEG (64-bit)
SET ffmpeg="C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -threads 1


::  *** MATCH INPUT FILE'S SETTINGS : Input file analysed by MediaInfo ***

::  **  Command Line : 2 Pass Encoding : 320 kbps x 2/3 + Headroom = 240 kbps : Input = MKV  **

::  Video - Advanced Video Codec (AVC), High@L5 - Constant Bitrate, Framerate defaults to Input file's framerate

::  Overwrite a Profile with the x264-params option
SET x264opts="ref=16:deblock=1,1,2:me_range=32:trellis=0:bframes=5:open_gop=0:min-keyint=300:keyint_min=23:bitrate=240:qpmin=12:qpmax=60:qpstep=10:threads=1"

SET mapping=-i "%input%" -itsoffset 0 -i "%input%"  -map 0:v -map 1:a  -copyts
SET options=-preset veryslow  -profile:v high -level 5 -x264-params %x264opts%  -pix_fmt yuv420p
SET command=%ffmpeg% %mapping% -c:v libx264 %options% -vf "scale=iw*%multiply%/%divide%:-1" -c:a copy  -sn  -map_metadata 0
%command% -y -pass 1 -flags global_header -f matroska nul  &&  %command% -pass 2 -flags global_header -movflags faststart "output_640x480_240kbps.mkv"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point "*reproducing the encoding used*". That's just historical info, and using the same settings won't result in more efficient re-encoding. If you want to lower processor burden, use a lower profile. `refs=16` and `bframes=5` will do exactly the opposite of *consume fewer processor cycles*. Single-pass CRF will do, no need for two passes average bitrate mode.

You also ingest the input twice and apply a TS offset of 0 (!). Why?

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:480:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -profile:v main -c:a copy -sn -map_metadata 0 out.mkv
```

You can omit the pad filter if the input is exactly 4:3.

If the resulting size is too large, increase the CRF value.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Perhaps I expressed myself badly: I am not trying to make the re-encoding process itself more efficient. I just want to end up with a smaller file, so that playback uses fewer resources than playing the much larger original file. I am trying to retain the original encoding parameters, so that the output file will most closely resemble the input file, quality-wise; but I wish to simplify the ffmpeg command line. I am hoping that there is a less cumbersome way of expressing the command line.

Comment: For example, can ffmpeg make use of the original parameters encoded in the input file? At present I am obtaining these manually, using MediaInfo to analyse the input file, then modifying my command line.

Comment: I am using 2-pass mode because my trials conclusively demonstrate that I get better compression - a smaller output file every time - if I use 2-pass encoding. Also, by including an '-itsoffset' of 0, coupled with the '-tscopy' option and '-map' options, I force the output file to mirror *all* the timestamps in the input file, however wacky the input file is, and I thereby get an *exactly* in-sync output file -- but, of course, if the input file was out-of-sync what I get is an *exactly* out-of-sync output file! (In the latter case, I have the option of omitting those options.)

Comment: *end up with a smaller file* --> file size is just one determinant of resource burden. And with your current settings, not the most burdensome one. refs=16 is a much bigger contributor. In any case, to lower file size, increase CRF. *retain the original encoding parameters* --> that's not how encoders work. For one thing, your source is not the same as the original source. The error residuals will be different so your clamping of qp in x264opts could be suboptimal. Your me_range may be unnecessarily too high for a 2nd generation encode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below artifact to handle the video and image resizing.

URL for Project dependency(Available for Maven, Gradle, Scala etc..): [Click Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.techgnious/IVCompressor)

It is built on top on FFMPEG. You don't have to manually handle the logic.

This artifact helps in achieving the solution without much of boiler plate code in our logic

Sample Usage::

```
IVCompressor compress=new IVCompressor();
byte[] Imageoutput=compress.resizeImage(data, fileFormat, resolution); //for image compression
byte[] VideoOutput=compress.reduceVideoSize(videoData, fileFormat, resolution);//for video compression
```

Know more details @[IVCompressor](https://techgnious.github.io/IVCompressor/)